# JQuery Event repeating in dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a page of a website I'm making, the press of a button imports the contents of a another php page and appends it onto the page. However, that other page contains JQuery, and the click event($( ".ExpandRoleButton").click) repeats itself on previous elements every time I import the content. So if I add 3 elements;

Element 1: Repeats the click event 3 times

Element 2: Repeats the click event 2 times

Element 3: Runs the click event once

```
$("#AjouterPiece").click(function() 
{
    $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="images/ChargementGeant.gif"/><br/><h1>Un moment svp.</h1>' });
    $.post("wizardincl/piste.php", {newPiste: newPiste}, function(data)
    {
        $("#wizardPistes").append(data);
        $.unblockUI();
        $(".divNewPiste").fadeTo(300, 1);
        $("#nbExemplaires").attr("max", newPiste);
        newPiste++

        $( ".ExpandRoleButton").click(function()
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass('RetractRoleButton'))
            {
                $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/ExpandPetitNoir.png');
                var that = $(this);
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().slideUp(500, function() {
                    that.parent().parent().parent().parent().css('border-bottom', '1px solid #FF790B');
                });
                $(this).removeClass('RetractRoleButton');
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().css('border-bottom', 'none');
                $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/ExpandPetitNoirRetour.png');
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next().slideDown(500);
                $(this).addClass('RetractRoleButton');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Currently, part of the JQuery website seems down and after some search, I can't find anything to solve the problem. Is there any way to keep the code from repeating itself like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are binding the event to multiple event handlers. The first time `#AjouterPiece` is clicked, all `.ExpandRoleButton` buttons get binded to an onclick handler.

The next time `#AjouterPiece` is clicked, it gets binded again.

To prevent this, you must `unbind` the click handlers using the following code before binding it

```
$( ".ExpandRoleButton").unbind('click')
```

Comment: Why did I forget this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can pass in the event with `.click(function(e) {...})` and then call `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` to fire only the current handler, but that only addresses the symptom, not the real problem.

Edit: make sure you are only binding the new instance of the button by adding a context to your selector, like `$('.ExpandRoleButton', data)`. Since you are matching on a class, that selector will grab all the buttons on the page; the context allows you to select only the one inside your result.

Comment: What is the real problem, and what could I do to fix it? The JQuery concerning the dynamic content which is only called after the page is loaded needs to have the JQuery included in it, else it just doesn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that the data I'm bringing in is almost always identical be a problem? Also, just unbinding the event before adding it seems to work. EDIT: Tried adding the context, it just makes the function not work, probably doing it wrong. Replaced $( ".ExpandRoleButton").click(function() by $( ".ExpandRoleButton", data).click(function()

Comment: Maybe data is out of scope? The data is mostly HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice ( solely to prevent issues like this from occurring, unintended multiple click handlers added ) is to..

```
$(".selector").off('click').on('click', function...
```

or

```
$(".selector").unbind('click')...
$(".selector").bind('click')...
```