# javascript onclick is repeating itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, bind

I have these two block of Javascript codes. Essentially what I want to do is use the Enter button and the "next_layer" button for the same thing "go to the next task, and load the next figures", but once I Click, the program loops over itself forever, like if the "onclick" was always activated. As a solution, I temporarily used:

```
this.bind('click');
```

but it only works for the first iteration. How do I 'unbind/reset' this so it works for the next iterations as well? Or is there another more elegant solution that doesn't require me to use the 'bind() or unbind() commands?

Code blocks:

```
$('.next_layer').click(function(){
var id=this.id;
var validate=validateForm(id);
if(validate){

var idns=parseInt(id)+1;
var idcath="layer"+id;
var idcats="layer"+idns;
if(idns==20)$('#submitButton').css("display","block");

$('#'+idcath).css("visibility", "hidden");
$('#'+idcats).css("visibility", "visible");

$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}

//kinda works!
//this.bind('click');
return false;
});
```

and:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    //var stop1 = 0;
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
        $('.next_layer').click();
        }
});
```

**[EDIT]:** My problem is very similar to this thread: 
[JQuery Event repeating in dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465356/jquery-event-repeating-in-dynamic-content)

Here is the complete HTML code:

```
<div id="layer1" class="layers">
<table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center>Image A</center></td>
            <td><center>Image B</center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url1a1}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image1_11" /></td>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url1b1}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image2_11" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center>             <label style="font-size: 16px;">Which of these images will go Viral? Image A or Image B?</label>       </center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageA" name="share1_11" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image A</label></center></td>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageB" name="share1_11" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image B</label></center></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p>[Optional] Enter any comments here:</p>
<p><textarea name="summary1" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
<p><style type="text/css">
<!--
.highlight-box { border:solid 0px #98BE10; background:#FCF9CE; color:#222222; padding:4px; text-align:left; font-size: smaller;}
-->
</style></p>
<div class="next_layer" id=1 >Next</div>
</div>

<div id="layer2" class="layers">
<table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center>Image A</center></td>
            <td><center>Image B</center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url1a2}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image1_12" /></td>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url1b2}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image2_12" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center>             <label style="font-size: 16px;">Which of these images will go Viral? Image A or Image B?</label>       </center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageA" name="share1_12" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image A</label></center></td>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageB" name="share1_12" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image B</label></center></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p>[Optional] Enter any comments here:</p>
<p><textarea name="summary2" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
<p><style type="text/css">
<!--
.highlight-box { border:solid 0px #98BE10; background:#FCF9CE; color:#222222; padding:4px; text-align:left; font-size: smaller;}
-->
</style></p>
<div class="next_layer" id=2 >Next</div>
</div>

<div id="layer3" class="layers">
<table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center>Image A</center></td>
            <td><center>Image B</center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url1a3}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image1_13" /></td>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url1b3}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image2_13" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center>             <label style="font-size: 16px;">Which of these images will go Viral? Image A or Image B?</label>       </center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageA" name="share1_13" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image A</label></center></td>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageB" name="share1_13" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image B</label></center></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p>[Optional] Enter any comments here:</p>
<p><textarea name="summary3" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
<p><style type="text/css">
<!--
.highlight-box { border:solid 0px #98BE10; background:#FCF9CE; color:#222222; padding:4px; text-align:left; font-size: smaller;}
-->
</style></p>
<div class="next_layer" id=3 >Next</div>
</div>

<div id="layer4" class="layers">
<table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center>Image A</center></td>
            <td><center>Image B</center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url1a4}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image1_14" /></td>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url1b4}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image2_14" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center>             <label style="font-size: 16px;">Which of these images will go Viral? Image A or Image B?</label>       </center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageA" name="share1_14" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image A</label></center></td>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageB" name="share1_14" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image B</label></center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><center><label style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Did Image A surprise you?</b></label>        
<input type="radio" value="Yes1a" name="seen1a_14" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Yes</label>                
<input type="radio" value="No1a" name="seen1a_14" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">No </label></center></td>
            <td><center><label style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Did Image B surprise you?</b></label>        
<input type="radio" value="Yes1b" name="seen1b_14" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Yes</label>                
<input type="radio" value="No1b" name="seen1b_14" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">No</label></center></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p>[Optional] Enter any comments here:</p>
<p><textarea name="summary4" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
<p><style type="text/css">
<!--
.highlight-box { border:solid 0px #98BE10; background:#FCF9CE; color:#222222; padding:4px; text-align:left; font-size: smaller;}
-->
</style></p>
<div class="next_layer" id=4 >Next</div>
</div>

<!----- 2nd pair----->
These pairs are analogously the same as the 1st and 5th. They were cut off due to spacing restrictions.
<!----- 3rd pair----->

<!----- 4th pair----->

<!----- 5th pair----->

<div id="layer17" class="layers">
<table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center>Image A</center></td>
            <td><center>Image B</center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url5a1}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image9_27" /></td>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url5b1}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image10_27" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center>             <label style="font-size: 16px;">Which of these images will go Viral? Image A or Image B?</label>       </center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageA" name="share5_27" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image A</label></center></td>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageB" name="share5_27" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image B</label></center></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p>[Optional] Enter any comments here:</p>
<p><textarea name="summary17" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
<p><style type="text/css">
<!--
.highlight-box { border:solid 0px #98BE10; background:#FCF9CE; color:#222222; padding:4px; text-align:left; font-size: smaller;}
-->
</style></p>
<div class="next_layer" id=17 >Next</div>
</div>


<div id="layer18" class="layers">
<table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center>Image A</center></td>
            <td><center>Image B</center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url5a2}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image9_28" /></td>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url5b2}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image10_28" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center>             <label style="font-size: 16px;">Which of these images will go Viral? Image A or Image B?</label>       </center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageA" name="share5_28" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image A</label></center></td>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageB" name="share5_28" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image B</label></center></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p>[Optional] Enter any comments here:</p>
<p><textarea name="summary18" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
<p><style type="text/css">
<!--
.highlight-box { border:solid 0px #98BE10; background:#FCF9CE; color:#222222; padding:4px; text-align:left; font-size: smaller;}
-->
</style></p>
<div class="next_layer" id=18 >Next</div>
</div>

<div id="layer19" class="layers">
<table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center>Image A</center></td>
            <td><center>Image B</center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url5a3}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image9_29" /></td>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url5b3}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image10_29" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center>             <label style="font-size: 16px;">Which of these images will go Viral? Image A or Image B?</label>       </center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageA" name="share5_29" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image A</label></center></td>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageB" name="share5_29" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image B</label></center></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p>[Optional] Enter any comments here:</p>
<p><textarea name="summary19" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
<p><style type="text/css">
<!--
.highlight-box { border:solid 0px #98BE10; background:#FCF9CE; color:#222222; padding:4px; text-align:left; font-size: smaller;}
-->
</style></p>
<div class="next_layer" id=19 >Next</div>
</div>

<div id="layer20" class="layers">
<table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center>Image A</center></td>
            <td><center>Image B</center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url5a4}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image9_30" /></td>
            <td><img width="360" height="360" src="${image_url5b4}" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-left: 75px;" alt="image10_30" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center>             <label style="font-size: 16px;">Which of these images will go Viral? Image A or Image B?</label>       </center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageA" name="share5_30" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image A</label></center></td>
            <td><center><input type="radio" value="ImageB" name="share5_30" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Image B</label></center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><center><label style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Did Image A surprise you?</b></label>        
<input type="radio" value="Yes5a" name="seen5a_30" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Yes</label>                
<input type="radio" value="No5a" name="seen5a_30" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">No </label></center></td>
            <td><center><label style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Did Image B surprise you?</b></label>        
<input type="radio" value="Yes5b" name="seen5b_30" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">Yes</label>                
<input type="radio" value="No5b" name="seen5b_30" /><label style="font-size: 16px;">No</label></center></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<p>[Optional] Enter any comments here:</p>
<p><textarea name="summary20" cols="80" rows="3"></textarea></p>
<p><style type="text/css">
<!--
.highlight-box { border:solid 0px #98BE10; background:#FCF9CE; color:#222222; padding:4px; text-align:left; font-size: smaller;}
-->
</style></p>
<!--<div class="next_layer" id=4 >Next</div>-->
</div>
```

Here is the complete javascript code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <script>

window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('submitButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'return validateForm(20)');$('#submitButton').css("display","none");$('#submitButton').css("position","absolute");$('#submitButton').css("top","860px");}


$('#layer1').css("visibility", "visible");

$('.next_layer').click(function(){
var id=this.id;
var validate=validateForm(id);
if(validate){

var idns=parseInt(id)+1;
var idcath="layer"+id;
var idcats="layer"+idns;
if(idns==20)$('#submitButton').css("display","block");

$('#'+idcath).css("visibility", "hidden");
$('#'+idcats).css("visibility", "visible");

//alert("trycatch");
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}
//this.unbind('click')
//else alert("nonval");

//kinda works!
//this.bind('click');
//this.rebind('click');
//return false;
});

$('.next_layer').keyup(function(){
var id=this.id;
var validate=validateForm(id);
if(validate){

var idns=parseInt(id)+1;
var idcath="layer"+id;
var idcats="layer"+idns;
if(idns==20)$('#submitButton').css("display","block");

$('#'+idcath).css("visibility", "hidden");
$('#'+idcats).css("visibility", "visible");

//alert("trycatch");
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}
//this.unbind('click')
//else alert("nonval");

//kinda works!
this.bind('keyup');
//this.rebind('click');
return false;
});


function validateForm(id) {
 var empty = false;
    $(':radio').each(function() {
        nam = $(this).attr('name');
nam_last=nam.substr(nam.length-2);
if(parseInt(nam_last)==parseInt(id)+10){
        if (!$(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]:checked').length) { 

           empty = true;
        }
}
    });


if (!empty)
return true;
else{
alert("Please answer all the questions!");
return false;
}
}

$(document).keypress(function(event){
    //var stop1 = 0;
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
        $('.next_layer').keyup();
        }
});

//$(document).unbind("click", event);

//$('#foo').bind('click', handler);
//$('#foo').unbind('click', handler);

</script>
```

Comment: I'm finding it hard to see a code path that would cause an infinite loop in what you have provided. Is it possible for you to make a test case in jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: Hmm, would it help to say that the infinite looping is only present when I hit the enter key, but not when I directly click on the "next_layer" button?

Comment: does it happen if you change the listener to `.keyup`?

Comment: yeah it still happens, I even created another alternate function with the .keyup listener. So I can separate the function of clicking the button, and hitting enter. The only thing I can't understand is why it works perfectly for the first time when use this.bind('click'), but it stops working once the next dynamic content is loaded. I've read stuff about unbind and rebind but I'm not sure how to use it...

Comment: could you post your HTML?

Comment: Ok, check edit. It's long though, about 600 lines of code.

Comment: Could you please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead posting whole code here?

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually have an infinite loop.  What is happening is that the selector `$('.next_layer')` is selecting *all* elements with the next_layer class, regardless of visibility, so your line

```
$('.next_layer').click();
```

effectively clicks them all at once.

A suggestion to do this differently:
Instead of explicitly changing visiblity on each element, define a couple of CSS classes like hidden and visible that contain the appropriate options.  Use `removeClass` and `addClass` to change to the next element

```
$('#'+idcath).removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
$('#'+idcats).removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
```

Then you could use

```
$('.next_layer.visible').click();
```

so you only click the one that is visible.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BsjXX/)

If for some reason you can't use CSS, you could set an attribute on the elements:

```
$('#'+idcath).css("visibility", "hidden").attr('active','false');
$('#'+idcats).css("visibility", "visible").attr('active','true');
```

and to click just the active one, your keypress handler would use:

```
$('.next_layer[active="true"]').click();
```